# Sequelize - How to search multiple columns?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database of articles with several columns and would like to be able to search both `title` and `description`.

Currently, I have:

```
Article.findAll({
  where: {
    title: { like: '%' + searchQuery + '%' }
  }
});
```

How can I also search the description as well?

I've read through [the sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#data-retrieval-finders), even in the `Complex filtering / OR / NOT queries` section, but the examples only seem to explain searching in one column.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Sequelize >= 4.12

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
Article.findAll({
  where: {
    title: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchQuery + '%' },
    description: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchQuery2 + '%' }
  }
});
```

### Sequelize < 4.12

```
Article.findAll({
  where: {
    title: { like: '%' + searchQuery + '%' },
    description: { like: '%' + searchQuery2 + '%' }
  }
});
```

---

The above will make sure `title` includes `searchQuery` **and** `description` includes `searchQuery2`. If you however would like to get results back when an Article includes one of the two, the following query should work:

### Sequelize >= 4.12

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
Article.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
     title: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchQuery + '%' },
     description: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchQuery2 + '%' }
    ]
  }
});
```

### Sequelize < 4.12

```
Article.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
     title: { like: '%' + searchQuery + '%' },
     description: { like: '%' + searchQuery2 + '%' }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: The syntax for logical operations is modified in the latest version of sequelize, please check http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Comment: @SohamLawar thanks for the heads up, I've added it to the answer as preferred way for Sequelize 4.12 and up.

Comment: Good job,@leroydev

Comment: This is still forcing that the record include both a title and description. What if one of my params is not included?

Comment: Is there a possibility to search by all columns inside table without explicitly saying which column to search in? @leroydev

Comment: @BartusZak Please create a new question for that question. :)

Answer (score 7):

**Sequelize >= 4.12**

```
Article.findAll({
 where = {
  [Op.or]: [
    { name: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.query_string}%` } },
    { description: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.query_string}%` } }
  ]
}
});
```

just fyi: mysql doesn't supports iLike ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
where: {
  [op.or]: [
    {
      model: {
        [op.like]: `%${ req.query.search }%`
      }
    },
    {
      description: {
        [op.like]: `%${ req.query.search }%`
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is the first time i've heard of sequelize.js but I looked at the doco and found this:

```
Project.findOne({
  where: {
    name: 'a project',
    $or: [
      { id: [1,2,3] },
      { id: { $gt: 10 } }
    ]
  }
})

Project.findOne({
  where: {
    name: 'a project',
    id: {
      $or: [
        [1,2,3],
        { $gt: 10 }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Both pieces of code code will generate the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Projects`
WHERE (
  `Projects`.`name` = 'a project'
   AND (`Projects`.`id` IN (1,2,3) OR `Projects`.`id` > 10)
)
LIMIT 1;
```

The section above those examples gives the various clauses permitted including `$and` and `$or`:

```
Project.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      $and: {a: 5}           // AND (a = 5)
      $or: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}]  // (a = 5 OR a = 6)
  ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but correct me if I'm mistaken, but does this still not only search one column? (in this example `Projects.id`)

Comment: I think these joiners can be used within the `where` between fields. See the `$not example` near these ones for use with two different columns.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in sequelize 6. Sequelize docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255792/sequelize-how-to-search-multiple-columns/34263873 mention very few available options for findOne. Options mentioned in this answer are supported in findAll method, but not findOne.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to search over all columns in Model Sequelize here is example which you will cast every col to varchar to be able to use ilike operator and pushing them in array which will be the where clausel. I mean with repo in the example is the sequelize model.

```
    async findFilterAndCountAll(pg: { limit : number, offset : number, sort:string, order: string, pfilter : any}) {
        var filters = Array();
        for (const key in this.repo.rawAttributes ) {
            console.log(key);
            filters.push(sequelize.where(
                sequelize.cast(sequelize.col(key), 'varchar'),
                {[Op.iLike]: `%tes%`}
              ))
        }
        return await this.repo.findAndCountAll({
            limit : pg.limit,
            offset : pg.offset,
            order: [
                [pg.order, pg.sort]
            ],
            where : {
                [Op.or]: filters
            }
        }); 
    }
```